# Go through all databases in the server to get specific data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Would it be possible to write a script that goes through each database object on the server and get specific data I need? It would be something like - each object that contains an address or e-mail

EDIT: I basically need to find database objects that contain client info's. How is it possible to find all objects that contain '@' (as in for e-mails)?

Comment: An object in SQL Server is anything in the database (eg. user defined functions and indexes are objects): please refine your question to be more specific to what you want to check (and update the question with the information).

Comment: Yes it would be possible

Comment: It's possible, but how would you identify such data? You could probably easily do something for email addresses, but a property address can be hard to identify unless the column actually has "address" in the name.

Comment: @Apep, I'd assume, that - if there is at least an eMail-address somewhere, this table might contain other *address* related data too. You might search for any occurance of typical fragments like `@`, `street`, `road` and so on... See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL [sp_MSForEachTable](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-exec-sp_msforeachdb-sp_msforeachtable-example-tsql-code.aspx) procedure as an option
In the reference document there is a SQL script which returns all database tables and their columns (just as an example)

It is also possible to execute the same script on all databases on the same SQL Server instance using sp_MSForEachDB, too

But if you are looking for database table columns with name like address, or email you can also use following SQL Select statement

```
select 
    object_name(c.object_id) [object name], 
    o.type_desc [object type],
    c.name [column name] 
from sys.columns as c
inner join sys.objects as o
    on c.object_id = o.object_id
where c.name like '%address%' or c.name like '%email%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tbl(TableName VARCHAR(255),ColumnName VARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @SearchFor VARCHAR(100)='@'
```

--Use diffferent fragments here, you can use 'street' or 'road' or anything else

```sql
DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT
'INSERT INTO #tbl(TableName,ColumnName)
 SELECT ''' + CONCAT(c.TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',c.TABLE_NAME) + ''',''' + c.COLUMN_NAME + '''
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ' + CONCAT(QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_SCHEMA),'.',QUOTENAME(c.TABLE_NAME)) + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) +' LIKE ''%' + @SearchFor +'%'');'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.DATA_TYPE LIKE '%char%';

OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @stmt;
EXEC(@stmt);
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @stmt;
    EXEC(@stmt);
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

SELECT * FROM #tbl;
GO
DROP TABLE #tbl;
```

One of the rare situations where a `CURSOR` is needed.
The cursor will contain a lot of statements, that are built from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`. If there is at least one row with the search value the table and column name is added to the result table.

Each statement will look similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO #tbl(TableName,ColumnName)
 SELECT 'dbo.SomeTable','SomeColumn'
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] WHERE [SomeColumn] LIKE '%@%');
```